# xlwt: write multiple columns

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I have a file containing data like below

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
```

I am trying to write this to a excel file in 4 columns using xlwt in python. I want to do it in excel as I need to create multiple sheets in same file.
There is lot of examples on how to write 2 columns by looping, but I couldn't find an example of writing multiple columns. Can any body tell me how to get this done ?

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what you are looking for:

```
import xlwt

data1 = [["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"], ["e1", "f1", "g1", "h1"], ["i1", "j1", "k1", "l1"]]
data2 = [["a2", "b2", "c2", "d2"], ["e2", "f2", "g2", "h2"], ["i2", "j2", "k2", "l2"]]
data3 = [["a3", "b3", "c3", "d3"], ["e3", "f3", "g3", "h3"], ["i3", "j3", "k3", "l3"]]

sheets = ["Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3"]

wb = xlwt.Workbook()

for sheet, data in zip(sheets, [data1, data2, data3]):
    ws = wb.add_sheet(sheet)

    for row, row_value in enumerate(data):
        for col, col_value in enumerate(row_value):
            ws.write(row, col, col_value)

wb.save('output.xls')
```

This would give you an Excel file looking like:

[image: Excel screenshot]